# Python Dictionary: Key with two values possible?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

For a test program I'm crawling a webpage. I'd like to crawl all activites for specifid ID´s which are associated to the respective cities.

For example, my initial code:

```
RegionIDArray = {522: "London", 4745: "London", 2718: "London", 3487: "Tokio"}
```

Im now wondering if its possible to sum up all IDs (values) which are related to e.g. London into one key:

```
RegionIDArray = {522, 4745, 2718: "London}
```

If I´m trying this, I get no results

My full code so far

```
RegionIDArray = {522: "London", 4745: "London", 2718: "London", 3487: "Tokio"}

for reg in RegionIDArray:
    r = requests.get("https://www.getyourguide.de/-l" +str(reg) +"/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    g_data = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "intro-title"})
    for item in g_data:
        POI_final = (str(item.text))

        end_final = ("POI: " + POI_final)
        if end_final not in already_printed:
           print(end_final)
           already_printed.add(end_final)
```

Is there any smart way.Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You mean value with two keys?

Comment: you need to have one `key` and many `values`

Comment: *"Im now wondering if its possible to sum up all IDs (values) which are related to e.g. London into one key"*, I don't really understand what you're asking, do you want to use the sum? a tuple? have each key work individually?

Comment: Do you mean sum them or have those 3 numbers still broken out?

Comment: I don't see where you are using the values (London for instance) in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 2 steps:

1. Create a dictionary mapping locations to list of IDs.
2. Reverse this dictionary, taking care to ensure your keys are hashable.

The first step is optimally processed via `collections.defaultdict`.

For the second step, you can use either `tuple` or `frozenset`. I opt for the latter since it is not clear that ordering is relevant.

```
from collections import defaultdict

RegionIDArray = {522: "London", 4745: "London", 2718: "London", 3487: "Tokio"}

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in RegionIDArray.items():
    d[v].append(k)

res = {frozenset(v): k for k, v in d.items()}

print(res)

{frozenset({522, 2718, 4745}): 'London',
 frozenset({3487}): 'Tokio'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
RegionIDArray = {522: "London", 4745: "London", 2718: "London", 3487: "Tokio"}
new_results = {tuple(c for c, _ in b):a for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(RegionIDArray.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])}
```

Output:

```
{(3487,): 'Tokio', (4745, 522, 2718): 'London'}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is make a reverse lookup table from the values to all working keys, like so:

```
def reverse(ids):
    table = {}
    for key in ids:
        if ids[key] not in table:
            table[ids[key]] = []
        table[ids[key]].append(key)
    return table
```

Comment: Wait now... you should use setdefault or collections defaultdict for this. But it is not what OP wants.

Comment: @AntonvBR Then what did OP want